# Do I need hyphen in this context?

Tags: hyphens

> That algorithm suffers from not-sufficient-enough data modelling techniques.

or

> That algorithm suffers from not sufficient enough data modelling techniques.

**Hint:** The algorithm's modelling techniques are good but not enough to achieve my purposes.

Comment: I'm perplexed. Why would you not simplify this, and use _insufficient_ instead?

Comment: @J.R. I forgot about that word. but does not-sufficient enough has the same meaning as insufficient ?

Comment: It may have the same meaning, but it's a terrible way to say it.

Comment: @J.R. so you are suggesting to replace my word with a word that doesn't have the same meaning ?

Comment: No, I'm suggesting that you rephrase the sentence so that it doesn't sound horrible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the hyphens are necessary. It is hard to read otherwise. The hyphens make it clear that "not sufficient enough" is a single modifier that applies to "data." Otherwise, it looks like you are saying "The algorithm suffers from not sufficient enough data," and then when I get to "modelling techniques," I wouldn't even know how that fits into the sentence.

But I should point out that this sort of three-word modifier is informal no matter how you write it. Also, "sufficient" and "enough" are roughly synonymous, and putting them together this way is sort of unclear and redundant.

If you are writing for something like a formal essay, it would be better to write

> That algorithm suffers from insufficient data modelling techniques.

or

> That algorithm suffers from data modelling techniques that are not sufficient.

Comment: does insufficient imply that they are good but not good enough ?

Comment: Insufficient means "not enough." It doesn't necessarily mean "good" or "not good enough" - for example, you could write, "The money in his account was insufficient to buy a house." That just means it's not enough money. It doesn't mean the money isn't good enough.

Comment: then , i would prefer to change this sufficient. do you have any other suggestion please ?

Comment: [_inadequate_](http://onelook.com/?w=inadequate&ls=a) might be a better word to use...